TiaGo JointGroupVelocityController not working properly ROS2
I am tryinng to implement velocity controller (JointGroupVelocityController from ros2_comntrol) for the TiaGo's manipulator. The yaml file setup is pretty straight foreward and looks like this:
arm_velocitiy_controller:
 ros__parameters:

   type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController

   joints:
     - arm_1_joint
     - arm_2_joint
     - arm_3_joint
     - arm_4_joint
     - arm_5_joint
     - arm_6_joint
     - arm_7_joint

When I publish the desired joint velocities, the manipulator starts moving but the velocities are much slower for some joints ( I check this via /joint_state topic). So, maybe 2/7 joints move with the correct velocities while others have significantly lower velocities, for example:
Published velocities: [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
Actual velocities: [0.0480, 0.035, 0.0051, 0.019, 0.0377, -0.050, 0.014]

I have also checked for mechanical reductions in the URDF but they are all set to 1. Also none of the joint velocity limits are breached.
Can anyone perhaps recommned some solution or recommendation for the velocity controller?
I am using ros2 Humble and I simulate TiaGo in Gazebo.

I believe this is something to do with the gazebo simulation itself not the ros2_control part. It is better if you raise an issue in the repo : https://github.com/pal-robotics/tiago_simulation
